# Send file contents in place of file name - Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, file-io

I am using a module with function `foo(bar)` where `bar` is supposed to be a `str` that contains the path for a text file that is read-in within `foo`.

Is it possible to create `my_str = str(...)` that contains the text that would otherwise be in `bar` and somehow pass `my_str` to `foo` in place of the text file.

Right off the bat, I would assume that this is not possible. It seems that if `bar` is used within `open(bar, 'r')`, then passing content to a function that is asking for a path does not make sense. Nonetheless I wanted to check with the stack's collective intelligence. Thanks.

Comment: I'm confused what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: I mean if you're trying to parse the file you can just use `readline` or `readlines` to get the contents of the text file.

Comment: Lets say that `bar` is a password of some kind and it is supposed to reside in a file in the same directory as the python script that I am writing. Rather then use a file, I would like to hard code the password into the script (never mind the security implications). However, `foo` takes in a path in the form of a string. Other then writing a temp file using the script, are there any other ways to get my password into `foo`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could populate a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile) with the contents of your string and then pass in its `name` attribute. If you set it up with `delete=True` it'll auto-delete itself when it's closed.

Comment: I like. I realize that I just posted, without 'writing a temp file...,' but this simplifies the process. Other answers are still very much welcomed.